# Best way to overload a method when all you want to change is the return type

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, overload-resolution

Since return type can't be used to disambiguate methods what is the cleanest/best way to overload a method when all you want to change is the return type? Below is some sample code;

```
public static string Get(string url, Guid id, bool logResponse = true, bool baseKey = false)
{
     Tuple<string, int> response = Get(url, id, true, logResponse, baseKey);

     if (response.Item2 > 399)
        return null;
     return response.Item1;
}


public static Tuple<string, int> Get(string url, Guid id, bool returnStatus, bool logResponse = true, bool baseKey = false)
{
    // leaving out lots of code in this method, you should be able to get the point without it
    int http_status;  
    string response = CallApi(url, key, "GET", out http_status);

    return new Tuple<string, int>(response, http_status);
}
```

The above code works however I have an additional param ( returnStatus ) that serves no purpose, it's only there so the compiler can tell the difference between the two methods. Is there a better way to do this or am I just stuck adding useless parameters?

Comment: Why not just change the function name?

If you are doing different things in the different functions, and returning something different.  why do you want them named the same?  The function name should describe what is going on.  If you are returning something different in each function, the caller is going to have to know which one they are trying to execute anyway, and pass different parameters, so how is that better than naming the functions differently?

Comment: How about using an `out` parameter?

Comment: My approach would be to use a generic and then determine the type in the code. This would be pretty simple, and pretty scalable as well if you weren't doing something completely different if the types were different, which would probably be in whatever code is using the returned value.

Comment: @Caleb I want to keep the method names the same because I'm chaining them. In the one case I'm just returning more information to the caller. In the common case the caller won't care what the http status is as long as it's not 400 or above so they can just take null on error and the response otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change name of method, e.g.

```
string Get(string url, Guid id, bool logResponse)
Tuple<string, int> GetWithStatus(string url, Guid id, bool logResponse)
```

Main goal of programming is not to tell difference to compiler, but to tell difference to developers which will read your code. Another options is return status as `out` parameter:

```
string Get(string url, Guid id, bool logResponse, out int status)
```

I do not like `out` parameters very much, but I like tuples even less - what will tell name `Item2` to developer which uses your method? Is it status, or retries count, or maybe response length? Neither method name, nor return type cannot say what is it.

So, even for first case with renamed method I'd also changed return type to something like

```
public class ServerResponse
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; set; } // enum

    // use this in first method to check if request succeed
    public bool IsError
    {
       get { return (int)Status > 399; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm going to go the out param route. I think it's the cleanest thing here. With regard to Tuples values not being clear, a simple XML comment can communicate what values the Tuple contains.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal all comments tend to become outdated :) Btw there is nice option to rename first method to `GetContent` and second will be simple `Get`

Answer (score 2):

I see three options.

1. Return `object` and disambiguate in your calling method.
2. Make the method a generic, then detect the desired type using reflection.
3. Rename the method.

I'd choose #3. Make them "GetOne" and "GetTuple" and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the separation of concerns, if method doing different functions then we separate to two method (different method name).

But I will make one of them is private method for reflection loop, the first method will return generic type of T or just T (I maybe out of topic of Overloading, what I want to say is above example is return string, but for complex object, it can be many Overloading method to return different types, why not just return T, let the caller get object of T).

Overloading is good, depend on requirements.